# Google DFP - rotate creatives with different sizes

Tags: rotation, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

So, there is a campaign with two sizes, let's say: 970x250 and 300x250.
970x250 should run on desktop and 300x250 on mobile. The campaign has total impressions with no specific distribution between the two formats.

Size mapping, banner targeting etc. is properly configured, there is no issue with that. There is no 970x250 when using mobile and there is no 300x250 when using desktop.

Our traffic is 70% mobile and 30% desktop. I would suppose the serving of the two creatives should be approximately within the traffic distribution.

However, it appears that whatever setting is selected on "Rotate creatives" option in DFP, the mobile banner is getting over 95% of the impressions. It appears that "Rotate creatives" applies only for same sized creatives:
https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/99602?hl=en

Is there a way to specify let's say "weight" for the different size creatives, so the impression distribution is a bit more normal?

The only option that comes to my mind is second line item. But the traffic varies by desktop and mobile in weekdays and weekends and I was actually expecting that DFP will distribute the impressions based on the availability for each format. Which is not the case.

Comment: if you have an impression target, your adserver might not call your banner at every call. Do you confirm you are targeting 100% impressions ?

Comment: Hi, I am not targeting 100% of the impressions. What I basically want is to have different creatives for different devices but total impressions.

Comment: And to have the impressions split similarly to the actual daily traffic (which varies).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [weight the serving of creatives for a line item](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/99602?hl=en) but I've had trouble achieving my desired split when mobile/desktop inventory is available at different levels, (I'm guessing) because it seems that the imperative to serve the requested number of impressions is a higher priority than distribution between creatives.

I also experimented with [changing the delivery speed](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/82244?hl=en) of the campaign, but it didn't seem to help (note that my campaign was struggling to fulfil, so your mileage may vary).

I agree that a good workaround would be to create two line items within the same order, with the one targeting mobile, the other desktop, each with only the appropriate creative and number of impressions.

Comment: That's what we did. The major drawback is that during the weekend we have peak of mobile and sharp decline on desktop. I really though that Ad Manager will adjust this by itself, but it appears it doesn't work like that.